# uibutton color change(on/off)

Tags: xcode, uibutton

I want to make my UIButton just like a on/off button,
when i clicked the button,it turn on(Blue),
and if i clicked same button again,i hope it can turn off(default color)

i already make it can change color when it turn on,

`- (IBAction)OPEN:(id)sender {
    OPEN.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:154.0/255.0 blue:168.0/255.0 alpha:1];
}`

but i don't know how can i change it back to default color when clicked again,
Please help,Thanks.

Comment: Have you atleast searched for it on SO or google ?? You may find 1000 answers for this.

Comment: i have search it already,but i can't find any fit my case,or maybe i got wrong keyword searching,any link or keyword did i find in SO??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>When you change the color, set the button's highlighted state to "YES". Then when it is pressed check if it's already highlighted, if it is then change it back to grey background (or whatever color you want) and set highlighted to NO. This way the next time you press it, we will see that it is NOT already highlighted and we can set it to YES again and make it blue again.</s>

Use a BOOLEAN to toggle button background color.

```
BOOL isHighlighted;
-(IBAction)OPEN:(id)sender {
    if (isHighlighted == YES) {
        isHighlighted = NO;
        OPEN.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:154.0/255.0 blue:168.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    } else if (isHighlighted == NO) {
        isHighlighted = YES;
        OPEN.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:50.0/255.0 blue:50.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? It doesn't work the code? It doesn't work something else maybe? What is happening?

Comment: @MatchTsui changed the code to use a BOOLEAN instead.

Comment: but also the same problem,i have three button,and i want it all turn on,but look like got some error of that,when i clicked second button,the first button will turn off,why will be that?any idea to solve it?thanks

Comment: @MatchTsui you're probably using the same boolean valuable for the second button, you need to define a new BOOL. BOOL isHighlighted2;

Comment: i already make a new BOOL,"isHighlighted2"& "is Highlighted3",but also got that problem....

Answer (score 1):

In your ViewController.h file :-

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UIButton *toggleBtn;
    int toggleFlag;
}
- (IBAction)onTapBtn:(id)sender;
```

In your ViewController.m file :-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    toggleFlag = 1;
}

- (IBAction)onTapBtn:(id)sender {
    if (toggleFlag == 0) {

        // set whatever color you want for normal tap
        [toggleBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [toggleBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        toggleFlag = 1;
    }else if(toggleFlag == 1){
        // set whatever color you want after tap button
        [toggleBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [toggleBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        toggleFlag = 0;
    }

}
```

P.S. :- don't forget to connect the IBOutlet and IBAction for toggleButton. Please let me know your result.

Comment: i try this method ,it works~
but i got another problem,
actually i have three button,
i want to clicked it one by one,
but when i clicked one of them,it turn on,and when i clicked the second one,the first one was turn off,how can i make the first one keep on?

Comment: Firstly, what you asked in question is solved, so you should accept the answer first and then either ask another question or request to extend the question and ask for solution.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please ask another question or tell me what is your exact requirement now with 3 buttons ?

Comment: i can't ask it in other topic today~i used all my quote to ask question today. my problem is,if i used this method,when i tap the button,it's show on/off,but when i tap the other button after i tapped the first one, First button will keep switch when i tap,why should be that problem?

Comment: why ? , busy or another prob ?

Answer (score -1):

you can try with this, following methods should work. Both are different. try any.
as highlighted is a bool, it will change color accordingly.

**1)**

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

**2)**

```
- (void) setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    if (highlighted) {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x387038);
    }
    else {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x5bb75b);
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: how about the second one if i got two button ,and i want change separately?

Comment: you can pass setHighLighted:YES in your each button function. So that it will work accordingly for each one of them.

Comment: where did the second method put in?
and i dont know what is "pass setHighLighted:YES"
sorry for that ,and thanks